# 1 second latency for HTTP/1.1 100 Continue for ruby (puma, unicorn, webrick)

Tags: ruby, http

When I send a request to newly created rails application (with `rails new`) it works fast:

```
~ 冬 time curl -v -X POST --data key=value  http://localhost:3000/ok    
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 3000 (#0)
> POST /ok HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:3000
> User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 9
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* upload completely sent off: 9 out of 9 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< ETag: W/"a29ee2b15c494311c52521766e44af56"
< Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
< X-Request-Id: 99e6d922-dcd6-4e25-89a2-35fa735a401e
< X-Runtime: 0.003076
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< 
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
{"status":"ok"}curl -v -X POST --data key=value http://localhost:3000/ok  0.00s user 0.00s system 23% cpu 0.014 total
```

However, if I send a file or `multipart/form-data` it always take 1 second extra (`1.014 total`):

```
~ 冬 time curl -v -X POST --form key=value  http://localhost:3000/ok    
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 3000 (#0)
> POST /ok HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:3000
> User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 143
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------8cda3c76e0dbb84a
> 
* Done waiting for 100-continue
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< ETag: W/"a29ee2b15c494311c52521766e44af56"
< Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
< X-Request-Id: 13720420-bd08-44f8-8a98-aca57d70331a
< X-Runtime: 0.002236
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< 
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
{"status":"ok"}curl -v -X POST --form key=value http://localhost:3000/ok  0.01s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 1.014 total
```

application_controller.rb:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def ok
    render json: {status: 'ok'}
  end

end
```

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  post '/ok' => 'application#ok'
end
```

I tested this on several different linux machines and also, similar `php` code works without such delay.

Also, I tried to debug the puma server and found out that it freeze here:

```
# reactor.rb, line 29
while true
  begin
    ready = IO.select sockets, nil, nil, @sleep_for # waits one second here
    < ... >
```

The `sockets` argument contains `Puma::Client` instance and I don't have a clue how an object of this class can be passed to `IO.select`.

Any ideas on how to eliminate one second waiting?

Comment: sinatra also affected

Comment: what http-server do you use/ how do you start rails?

Comment: As well as possible server implementation considerations, this might be a Rack issue (Rack is the one parsing the request's POST body)... did you test this with [`iodine`](https://github.com/boazsegev/iodine) or [`passenger`](https://www.phusionpassenger.com)? They are both written in C, so they might supply faster HTTP parsing.

Comment: P.S. Larger POST data (and this is server dependent) will probably end up in a temporary file, to minimize the memory footprint. This will effect performance at the benefit of responsiveness towards other clients (assuming concurrency).

Comment: iodine gives the same result; I did not try passenger because we do not have the possibility to use it in our production environment

Comment: Felix, I tested this with puma, unicorn, and webrick

Comment: **Side-note**: Use the `@` sign before user names, so that the user gets a notification regarding the comma. i.e., Felix would have been notified of your comment had you written `"@" + "Felix"`: @Felix

Comment: Tested on [plezi.io](http://www.plezi.io) as well. This is probably caused by [Rack](https://rack.github.io), which is the interface between the servers and the frameworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to cURL and the [100-continue timeout](http://www.iandennismiller.com/posts/curl-http1-1-100-continue-and-multipartform-data-post.html).

In short, curl waits up to 1 second for your server to respond to the 100 Continue prior to sending the POST:

```
time curl --form key=value  http://google.com/

> real 0m1.067s
```

Vs:

```
time curl --expect100-timeout 0.001 --form key=value  http://google.com/

> real 0m0.086s
```

Comment: This was really tricky and I was sure the problem somewhere in rails...Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

I believe the issue is actually with the benchmark tool (`curl`) rather than the Ruby applications.

It seems that `curl` takes more time to both prepare and send the multipart/mime (form) request.

I wrote a quick Rack application to confirm the issue. Place the following code in `config.ru`:

```
require 'json'
app = proc do |env|
  req = Rack::Request.new(env)
  s = req.params.to_json
  [200, {"Content-Length": s.bytesize}, [s]]
end
run app
```

I ran the app using iodine with 8 threads:

```
$ iodine -t 8 -v
```

Testing with curl:

$ time curl -X POST --data key=value  http://localhost:3000/
{"key":"value"}
real    0m0.064s
user    0m0.004s
sys 0m0.003s

$ time curl --form key=value  http://localhost:3000/
{"key":"value"}
real    0m1.021s
user    0m0.004s
sys 0m0.004s

Issue exists when parsing the request.

Next, I removed the request parsing and simply sent back a static string (the new `config.ru`):

```
require 'json'
app = proc do |env|
  # req = Rack::Request.new(env)
  s = "GO!" # req.params.to_json
  [200, {"Content-Length": s.bytesize}, [s]]
end
run app
```

Results:

```
$ time curl --form key=value  http://localhost:3000/
GO!
real    0m1.019s
user    0m0.004s
sys 0m0.003s

$ time curl -X POST --data key=value  http://localhost:3000/
GO!
real    0m0.012s
user    0m0.004s
sys 0m0.003s
```

In other words, even when Ruby performs no parsing of the data (the multipart/mime isn't parsed), the issue persists.

I went ahead and tested with google...:

```
$time curl -X POST --data key=value  http://google.com/
...
real    0m0.090s
user    0m0.004s
sys 0m0.004s

$ time curl --form key=value  http://google.com/
...
real    0m1.083s
user    0m0.004s
sys 0m0.004s
```

The issue is with `curl` which takes more time to both prepare and send the request.